# Is AD Kennen a viable build for competitive play?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was looking at Kennen, and I saw two things that made me think he'd do okay as an AD champ:

Every 5th autoattack Ken does adds a Mark of the storm and deals 40% - 80% (based on rank) of his attack damage as magic damage.

His auto attack range is 575, making him very dangerous.

His AP side is very powerful already, so I wonder if AD kennen be looked upon for competitive play.

Comment: What do you mean by "Professional player" ? Can you provide more infomation about your question, please ? thank you sir.

Comment: Ranked/5v5 ranked teams for tournament play.

Comment: I thought they recently changed his W so it doesn't scale off of AD anymore? That would totally kill AD kennen imo.

Answer (score 2):

It has been done. Genja from M5 used AD Kennen effectively.

Here's a video, not sure if there are any guides, but I believe people rush Phantom Dancer's.

http://www.own3d.tv/video/418594/M5_-_AD_Kennen

Comment: You ninjad me. <3

Comment: http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=15498

<br/>http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/ad-kennen-m5-184390 

<br/>Two guides for reference as well OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Ad kennen is definitely a choice that some top laners make in tournaments. I see him used quite often.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if he's used in professional matches, but AD Kennen is viable if you build him with items that give attack damage with some attack speed, another variation would be on-hit Kennen build basing around attack speed and on-hit items.  Overall I don't think he's a good AD carry for professional play since other champions are more suited for it.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, there is a Russian team by the name of Moscow Five, arguably the best team right now, who runs AD Kennen. Here is a link to a video where they play vs SK at IEM Kiev.

The match starts at 30 minutes in.

AD Kennens strength lies in his utility(stuns), while still being able to deal the dmg.